# Scanning and adding data to arrays with unspecified delimiters

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have an assignment which requires me to work with the data below in a txt file.  There is no specified delimiter in which it would make it easier for me to sort into an array list.  I could use the `Scanner` class to read the text file and sort it into an array like:

```
for (int rows; rows < array.length; rows++){
array[rows][0] = fileIn.next();
array[rows][1] = fileIn.next();
```

and so on... However, the names are a bit harder since they have various numbers of white spaces in them and might have different numbers of names. I would like to have the whole name such as "Allison, Mrs. Hudson J C (Bessie Waldo Daniels)"  as its own element.  I'm not exactly sure where to start, but I think one solution is to have the program check if "male"||"female" is present so that we can start a new element. Any help would be appreciated.

```
1   1   Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton   female  29  211.3375
1   1   Allison, Master. Hudson Trevor  male    0.9167  151.5500
1   0   Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine    female  2   151.5500
1   0   Allison, Mr. Hudson Joshua Creighton    male    30  151.5500
1   0   Allison, Mrs. Hudson J C (Bessie Waldo Daniels) female  25  151.5500
1   1   Anderson, Mr. Harry male    48  26.5500
1   1   Andrews, Miss. Kornelia Theodosia   female  63  77.9583
1   0   Andrews, Mr. Thomas Jr  male    39  0.0000
1   1   Appleton, Mrs. Edward Dale (Charlotte Lamson)   female  53  51.4792
1   0   Artagaveytia, Mr. Ramon male    71  49.5042
1   0   Astor, Col. John Jacob  male    47  227.5250
1   1   Astor, Mrs. John Jacob (Madeleine Talmadge Force)   female  18  227.5250
1   1   Aubart, Mme. Leontine Pauline   female  24  69.3000
```

Comment: You can clearly see a delimiter here. **space**. Yes, the number of spaces vary. But you can split by spaces and remove the zero length strings in the resulting array

Comment: You might want to [learn](http://regexone.com/) about Regexs and then see [how](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) to use them in java

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha yes I know I can split by spaces.   However, I would get elements like "Astor,"  "Col."    "Dale"   I would like to get the **whole** name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a good fit for a regex - see [here](https://regex101.com/r/yU5fP3/1) for an example of your data.

```
([\d]) +([\d]) +(.+\S) +(female|male) +([\d.]+)  +([\d.]+)
```

---

[Here](https://repl.it/CaYw/0) the full example on repl.it in Java

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    public static void main( String args[] ){
        String text = 
            "1   1   Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton   female  29  211.3375\n"+
            "1   1   Allison, Master. Hudson Trevor  male    0.9167  151.5500\n"+
            "1   0   Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine    female  2   151.5500\n"+
            "1   0   Allison, Mr. Hudson Joshua Creighton    male    30  151.5500\n"+
            "1   0   Allison, Mrs. Hudson J C (Bessie Waldo Daniels) female  25  151.5500\n"+
            "1   1   Anderson, Mr. Harry male    48  26.5500\n"+
            "1   1   Andrews, Miss. Kornelia Theodosia   female  63  77.9583\n"+
            "1   0   Andrews, Mr. Thomas Jr  male    39  0.0000\n"+
            "1   1   Appleton, Mrs. Edward Dale (Charlotte Lamson)   female  53  51.4792\n"+
            "1   0   Artagaveytia, Mr. Ramon male    71  49.5042\n"+
            "1   0   Astor, Col. John Jacob  male    47  227.5250\n"+
            "1   1   Astor, Mrs. John Jacob (Madeleine Talmadge Force)   female  18  227.5250\n"+
            "1   1   Aubart, Mme. Leontine Pauline   female  24  69.3000\n";

        String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");

        String pattern = "([\\d]) +([\\d]) +(.+\\S) +(female|male) +([\\d.]+)  +([\\d.]+)";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        for (String l : lines) {
            Matcher m = r.matcher(l);
            if (m.find( )) {
                System.out.println(" ------------------- New Text Line -------------------");
                System.out.println("Group 1: " + m.group(1) );
                System.out.println("Group 2: " + m.group(2) );
                System.out.println("Group 3: " + m.group(3) );
                System.out.println("Group 4: " + m.group(4) );
                System.out.println("Group 5: " + m.group(5) );
                System.out.println("Group 6: " + m.group(6) );
            } else {
                System.out.println("Line did not match");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Would result in an output like so

```
 ------------------- New Text Line -------------------
Group 1: 1
Group 2: 1
Group 3: Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton
Group 4: female
Group 5: 29
Group 6: 211.3375
 ------------------- New Text Line -------------------
Group 1: 1
Group 2: 1
Group 3: Allison, Master. Hudson Trevor
Group 4: male
Group 5: 0.9167
Group 6: 151.5500
 ------------------- New Text Line -------------------
Group 1: 1
Group 2: 0
Group 3: Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine
Group 4: female
Group 5: 2
Group 6: 151.5500
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your own suggestion. You can use regular expressions to help parse everything between the initial two numbers and the "male|female".

Your code might look something like:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class test {

    private String[] parseLine(String line) {
        String[] output = new String[6];

        Pattern nonWhitespace = Pattern.compile("\\S+");
        Pattern sex = Pattern.compile( "\\s*(male|female)" );

        Matcher m = sex.matcher( line );

        if ( ! m.find() ) {
            // Handle errors. Couldn't find "male" or "female"
        }

        String firstHalf = line.substring(0, m.start());
        String lastHalf = line.substring(m.start(), INPUT.length());

        Matcher firstHalfTokenizer = nonWhitespace.matcher(firstHalf);

        if ( ! firstHalfTokenizer.find() ) {
             // Handle errors. Couldn't find any non-whitespace characters
        }

         output[0] = firstHalf.substring(firstHalfTokenizer.start(), firstHalfTokenizer.end()).trim();

         if ( ! firstHalfTokenizer.find() ) {
             // Handle errors. Couldn't find a second non-whitespace token
         }
         output[1] = firstHalf.substring(firstHalfTokenizer.start(), firstHalfTokenizer.end()).trim();

         output[2] = firstHalf.substring(firstHalfTokenizer.end(), firstHalf.length()).trim();

         Matcher lastHalfTokenizer = nonWhitespace.matcher(lastHalf);

         int index = 3;

         // Need to catch index-out-of-bounds errors if file has too many columns
         while( lastHalfTokenizer.find() ) {
             output[ index ] = lastHalf.substring(lastHalfTokenizer.start(), lastHalfTokenizer.end()).trim();
             index++;
         }

         return output;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          List<String[]> array = new ArrayList<String[]>();

          for ( String line in file ) { //XXX: Replace this with actual code to loop through the file
              array.add( parseLine(line) );
          }

          // Do whatever you want with it
      }
   }
```